# Searching Google with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am not able to do a simple google search through Selenium, although I believe I am doing it correctly. I attempted to follow the Selenium documentation, but I believe the issue might be caused by an improper install of python or selenium. I have little python knowledge. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "gbqfq")))
finally:
browser.quit()

search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("google search through python")
```

This is what terminal outputs.

```
 Mark-Kowalskys-iMac:~ markkowalsky$ cd '/Users/markkowalsky/Desktop/' && '/usr/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/markkowalsky/Desktop/searchGoogle.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/markkowalsky/Desktop/searchGoogle.py", line 14, in <module>
search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 302, in find_element_by_name
return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 662, in find_element
{'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 171, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 347, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 377, in _request
self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 874, in request
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 911, in _send_request
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 868, in endheaders
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 740, in _send_output
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 699, in send
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 683, in connect
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 512, in create_connection
socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

If you need any other information I will gladly share. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have an IndentationError in your finally block. Except from that I agree with the gist what Padraic Cunningham wrote.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your  `finally` block will be executed whether there has been an exception or not. So  `browser.quit()` is always executed.

If you want to just search this script will do it for you.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')

search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("google search through python")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) # hit return after you enter search text
time.sleep(5) # sleep for 5 seconds so you can see the results
browser.quit()
```

The [selenium docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) on `waits.

Comment: I'd not call browser.quit() immediately after the results are displayed. But - of course - this depends on what user3810035 is going to achieve with this script.

Comment: @Sebastian, it is just an example of how to search and to use sleep to wait between calls.

Comment: `quit()` is not in `finally` as not indented. Still it's executed if no exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

`driver.quit()` terminates the session at that point. Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "gbqfq")))

search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("google search through python")

browser.quit()
```

You mention that you have little python knowledge. It might be a good idea to either pick a language that you are already familiar with, or first got through some python tutorials to get yourself familiar with it.